# Summing data above until a blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum the data points (vlookup points) in above cells for a variable number of data rows. Each sum location is separated by a blank row in the report. I am getting an error in the Index portion of the formula to complete the sum.

The sum should be for all data points above when there is a data point in column C directly to the right. Is there an adjustment I need to make to the sum function or do I have the sum approach all wrong?

The third fourth and fifth data series have the sum manually entered to show what I need. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your help!

"=IFERROR(IF(C3<>"",SUM(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:$I$998="",0),0))),VLOOKUP(A3,'[179821 Invoice Status Report.xls]Subcontract Invoices'!$A$8:$AB$506,4,FALSE)),"")"

[Sum Above Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5QqC.png)

Comment: shouldn't `$I$998` be `$B$998`

Comment: You are also going to want to make the outer INDEX range match that of the inner or you will get the wrong reference.  So change `B:B` to `B2:$B$998`

Answer (score 0):

The range in your INDEX needs to be a single column. So if you change $I$998 to $B$998 it should work.